# NEST Search whole document C# Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to make a query over a million documents in Elasticsearch using Nest. My code:

```
var response = client.Search<MyObject>(s => s
          .Index("test")
          .Type("one")
          .Query(q => q.
                Term(
                    t => t.name, "A"
                )
          )
          .Size(10000)
          .Scroll("10m")
          .Pretty()
        );
```

My MyObject class:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is when this query is not found in the first 10k documents,  it won't continue searching the rest of the results scroll API.

My question is how to achieve this (i.e moving through the whole pages in Scroll API despite there is no hits..)?

Comment: var response = client.Search<MyObject>(search string, new SearchUrlParameters { Pretty = true }); replace this query

Comment: @silambarasanvediappan you sure of it, by default elastic enables only 10000 documents !

Comment: no, you have defined size as 10000, it's customization

Comment: maximum is 10K, So I used scroll API to handle 10k by 10k each page ...

Comment: ok, then put "from":0

Comment: Man, my question is how to loop the query over the pages in ScrollAPI even if there is a null hits... (Don't think it will solve the problem From(0))...But thanks anws for helping :)

Comment: Oh! then refer this http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: Yah I read that before, but all I wanted as first step is how to query over pages in scrollAPI. I know how to get the page through scrollID, but how to aplly a query upon this page ! And really thanks for help much appreciated .

Comment: @silambarasanvediappan really thanks, the problem was in the query, the string name "A" should be small letter (Note: dunno why !). Do you have any information about this !

Comment: Oh! good.,  this is because of term query finds exact term of search strings

Answer (score 5):

The query will search all documents, but will only return you the top `.Size` number of documents.

You can paginate results using `.From()` and `.Size()`, however, *deep pagination* is likely a concern when paginating over a million documents. For this, you would be better to use the [scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) to efficiently retrieve 1 million documents. NEST has an observable helper `ScrollAll()` to help with this

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

// number of slices in slice scroll
var numberOfSlices = 4;

var scrollObserver = client.ScrollAll<MyObject>("1m", numberOfSlices, s => s
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfSlices)
    .Search(search => search
        .Index("test")
        .Type("one")
        .Term(t => t.name, "A")
    )
).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), r =>
{
    // do something with documents from a given response.
    var documents = r.SearchResponse.Documents;
});
```

Comment: It worked for me, by just changing the letter 'A' to 'a' as silambarsan said. Here what exactly you are trying to do? Slicing each page into 4 slices? and search through the slices which they are the same as new pages?

Comment: I know this is very old, but I'm using ScrollAll and am needing to get the grand total of results included in my response.  I've tried `TrackTotalHits` but that just returns the total per slice.  Is there a good built-in way to do this?

Comment: @RussCam is this [ScrollAll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scrolling-documents.html) different than [SearchAfter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html)? What are the differences performance wise for large datasets? Where can i find a working example of SearchAfter other than [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/search-after-usage.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49489724/nest-api-searchafter-return-null-in-nest-but-works-in-kibana/49504560).

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol It's probably better to ask this as a new question. Essentially, `ScrollAll` is an observable implementation over the scroll API, which is an efficient way to retrieve a large number of documents in a forward-only, cursor style fashion. It does require keeping track of where a scroll is on the server side, so not recommended to have 1000s of scrolls running at any one time, and returns documents as they exist on scroll start.

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol `SearchAfter` is an efficient way to fetch documents that doesn't require keeping track on the server side, and can be used for next/previous deep pagination. The view on documents is live per search after request, so it can be possible for it to return duplicate documents if newly added documents would come before the current window of documents.