# Scrolling and Paging in Elastic/Nest 6+

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

**Intro**

I'm upgrading the elastic version to 6.3 (previously we were using 5.4.
Our app is written in C#, thus we use NEST.NET dll to talk with the Elastic server, so we are also updating it to the version 6.0.0.0.

**The use case - Before**

Until version 5, I was able to execute this query:

```
jsonStr =" 
   {
      "from": 16224,
      "size": 12,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "COMPANY": [
                        "AMP Services Ltd"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}"
```

Using this NEST/C# code:

```
Func<SearchRequestParameters, SearchRequestParameters> requestParameters = null;
requestParameters = a => a.Scroll(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
response = Connection.Client.GetInstance().LowLevel.Search<dynamic>("myindex", new PostData<dynamic>(jsonStr), requestParameters);
```

And with that, I was able to fetch the data without problems,

**The use case - NOW**

Now, with version 6, I'm trying to execute this very same query:

```
jsonStr ="
{
  "from": 16224,
  "size": 12,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "COMPANY": [
                    "AMP Services Ltd"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}"
```

Using this NEST/C# code (as the previus method signatures are no longer available):

```
SearchRequestParameters searchRequest = new SearchRequestParameters();
searchRequest.Scroll = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
response = Connection.Client.GetInstance().LowLevel.Search<StringResponse>("myindex", PostData.String(jsonStr), searchRequest);
```

And I'm getting this error: ***"Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"***

**Documentation**

I could not find anything in here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) and here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/sliced-scroll-search-usage.html) to help me replace this logic. Nothing in the forums either.

Do you guys have any insights on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks to be related to a [validation change in Elasticsearch in 6.0.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/26235); In 5.x, the `from` parameter was *allowed* for a scroll request but silently ignored. Now in 6.0.0, Elasticsearch is stricter and validates whether `from` is present for a scroll request and if it is, returns a bad response with an appropriate validation error.

Since a `from` parameter doesn't make sense for a scroll request, the solution to this is to do one of these two

1. Remove the `from` parameter when using the Scroll API
2. Continue to use the `from` parameter but do not use the Scroll API.

As an aside, If you are needing to scroll many documents, you may want to use [`ScrollAll()` observable helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816350/1831) to do so.

Comment: How do achieve #1? I mean removing from parameter using the Scroll API? If I try to pass null, that is ignored and gets default to 0.